# Deleting Duplicates in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have a table like this

```
userid  visitorid   time
1       10          2009-12-23
1       18          2009-12-06
1       18          2009-12-14
1       18          2009-12-18
1705    1678        2010-01-24
1705    1699        2010-01-24
1705    1700        2010-01-24
1712    1           2010-01-25
1712    640         2010-01-24
1712    925         2010-01-25
1712    1600        2010-01-24
1712    1630        2010-01-25
1712    1630        2010-01-24
1713    1           2010-01-24
1713    1           2010-01-23
```

I would like to perform a query such that it removes all the duplicates except for the latest one. I Hope you get an idea?

Example, after the query the table must be like this

```
userid  visitorid   time
1       10          2009-12-23
1       18          2009-12-18
1705    1678        2010-01-24
1705    1699        2010-01-24
1705    1700        2010-01-24
1712    1           2010-01-25
1712    640         2010-01-24
1712    925         2010-01-25
1712    1600        2010-01-24
1712    1630        2010-01-25
1713    1           2010-01-24
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Delete from YourTable VersionA
  where VersionA.Time NOT IN
    ( select MAX( VersionB.Time ) Time
         from YourTable VersionB
         where VersionA.UserID = VersionB.UserID
           and VersionA.VisitorID = VersionB.VisitorID )
```

Syntax might need to be adjusted, but SHOULD do the trick.  Additionally, you may want to pre-query the Subselect into its own table FIRST, then run the DELETE FROM against that result set.

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'VersionA where VersionA.Time NOT IN ( select MAX( VersionB.Time ) Time ' at line 1

Comment: is it possible to get unique rows neglecting the time field then delete all other rows except those and use the max time field ?

Comment: "Currently, you cannot delete from a table and select from the same table in a subquery." http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/delete.html - This is because the table is not locked correctly and no-one has implemented the code to lock it correctly yet.

Comment: Since I at not at a MySQL machine, I couldn't test, but the principle is correct... even if based on my subsequent comment to pre-query into its own table, then delete based on join to THAT resultset.  As for the Time, it should have been MAX(VersionB.Time) AS Time (or case-sensitive to match your construct)

Comment: lol dont get furious friend, actually that query went over my head lol so I posted the error directly,  tried to fix it but didnt work.

Comment: Sorry, didn't mean for the tone to sound ticked-off, just fact, no offense.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your table is called `Visitors`:

```
DELETE v1.* FROM Visitors v1
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT userid, visitorid, MAX(time) AS time
    FROM Visitors v2
    GROUP BY userid, visitorid
) v3 ON v1.userid=v3.userid AND v1.visitorid=v3.visitorid AND v1.time = v3.time
WHERE v3.userid IS NULL;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DELETE  mo.*
FROM    (
        SELECT  userid, visitorid, MAX(time) AS mtime
        FROM    mytable
        GROUP BY
                userid, visitorid
        ) mi
JOIN    mytable mo
ON      mo.userid = mi.userid
        AND mo.visitorid = mo.visitorid
        AND mo.time < mi.mtime
```

Comment: thanks but this deletes all rows except only one... i.e for the latest row for each user remains.

Answer (score 0):

You need to work around [MySQL bug#6980](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=6980), with a doubly nested subquery:

```sql
DELETE FROM foo_table
WHERE foo_table.time IN (
    SELECT time FROM (
        SELECT time FROM
            foo_table
            LEFT OUTER JOIN (
                SELECT MAX(time) AS time
                FROM foo_table
                GROUP BY userid, visitorid
                ) AS foo_table_keep
                    USING (time)
        WHERE
            foo_table_keep.time IS NULL
        ) AS foo_table_delete
    );
```

Using `GROUP BY` collapses duplicates down to a single row, and `MAX(time)` chooses which value you want. Use another aggregate function than `MAX` if you want.

Wrapping the subquery twice, providing aliases for each, avoids the error:

```
ERROR 1093 (HY000): You can't specify target table 'foo_table' for update in FROM clause
```

and has the extra advantage that it's clearer how the statement is choosing what to keep.