# Compacting tables after normalisation

Tags: mysql, database-normalization

I recently increased the level of normalisation in my database, going from something like this:

```
+--------------------------------------+
| state_changes                        |
+----+-------+-----------+------+------+
| ID | Name  | Timestamp | Val1 | Val2 |
+----+-------+-----------+------+------+
| 0  | John  | 17:19:01  |  A   |  X   |
| 1  | Bob   | 17:19:02  |  E   |  W   |
| 2  | John  | 17:19:05  |  E   |  Y   |
| 3  | John  | 17:19:06  |  B   |  Y   |
| 4  | John  | 17:19:12  |  C   |  Z   |
| 5  | John  | 17:19:15  |  A   |  Z   |
+----+-------+-----------+------+------+
```

To something more like this:

```
+-------------------------------+   +-------------------------------+
| state_changes_1               |   | state_changes_2               |
+----+-------+-----------+------+   +----+-------------------+------+
| ID | Name  | Timestamp | Val1 |   | ID | Name  | Timestamp | Val2 |
+----+-------+-----------+------+   +----+-------+-----------+------+
| 0  | John  | 17:19:01  |  A   |   | 0  | John  | 17:19:01  |  X   |
| 1  | Bob   | 17:19:02  |  E   |   | 1  | Bob   | 17:19:02  |  W   |
| 2  | John  | 17:19:05  |  E   |   | 2  | John  | 17:19:05  |  Y   |
| 3  | John  | 17:19:06  |  B   |   | 3  | John  | 17:19:06  |  Y   |
| 4  | John  | 17:19:12  |  C   |   | 4  | John  | 17:19:12  |  Z   |
| 5  | John  | 17:19:15  |  A   |   | 5  | John  | 17:19:15  |  Z   |
+----+-------+-----------+------+   +----+-------+-----------+------+
```

How could I now write a query to "compact" the two resulting tables where values are duplicated?

- I want to ignore the `ID` field when considering row uniqueness;
- I want to ignore the `Timestamp` when considering row uniqueness;
- *But* fields must be sequential (under a `Name,Timestamp` ordering) to be considered duplicates.

The result, in this example, should be:

```
+-------------------------------+   +-------------------------------+
| state_changes_1               |   | state_changes_2               |
+----+-------+-----------+------+   +----+-------+-----------+------+
| ID | Name  | Timestamp | Val1 |   | ID | Name  | Timestamp | Val2 |
+----+-------+-----------+------+   +----+-------+-----------+------+
| 0  | John  | 17:19:01  |  A   |   | 0  | John  | 17:19:01  |  X   |
| 1  | Bob   | 17:19:02  |  E   |   | 1  | Bob   | 17:19:02  |  W   |
| 3  | John  | 17:19:06  |  B   |   | 2  | John  | 17:19:05  |  Y   |
| 4  | John  | 17:19:12  |  C   |   | 4  | John  | 17:19:12  |  Z   |
| 5  | John  | 17:19:15  |  A   |   +----+-------+-----------+------+
+----+-------+-----------+------+
```

My tables have several billion rows so I'm looking for something that takes efficiency into consideration; that said, I'm a realistic sort of person so I'm happy for the query to take an hour or two to run (including index rebuilds) if needs be.

Comment: "But fields must be sequential (under a Timestamp ordering) to be considered duplicates". What's your max offset? 1 Second?

Comment: @Adrian: The `Timestamp` field is a `TIMESTAMP` with single-second resolution, and _may_ contain duplicates (in which case I don't care which row is considered to be "first", though technically it's usually the one with the highest `ID`).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2176686/deleting-duplicates-in-mysql _might_ do it but it doesn't appear to satisfy the requirement of consecutivity.

Comment: Please, explain why `4  | 17:19:15  |  A` is showing in state_changes_1 result set

Comment: @Adrian: The third bullet point. It's a state change from the previous state, which was `C`, and thus shall not be removed. The idea is to save space in the table by not keeping rows that used to indicate a state change but that, after the normalisation, no longer do.

Comment: http://www.artfulsoftware.com/infotree/queries.php#1160 looks promising

Comment: @MithleshUpadhyay That is not a "correction".

Comment: Sad to see two 40k+ users abusing the suggested edits system to further their own political agenda. :( @ildjarn

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit, sorry for that, can you define difference between normalization and normalisation, please?

Comment: @MithleshUpadhyay: "Normalisation" is the English word. "Normalization" is a USA variant. Both are acceptable here and changing one to the other is neither a "correction" nor an edit with sufficient weight to be worthy of the suggested edits system.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit, I got it, you are correct, that was not a correction. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried this on MySQL 5.1.58 and it seems to work with your test data.

```
SET @name = NULL;
SET @val1 = NULL;

UPDATE state_changes_1
SET Val1 = IF(Name=@name AND Val1=@val1, NULL, (@val1:=Val1)),
    Name = (@name:=Name)
ORDER BY Name, `Timestamp`;

DELETE FROM state_changes_1 WHERE Val1 IS NULL;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is your concept of 'sequential' or consecutive duplicate doesn't exist in relational algebra so won't be able to do it in sql. You can get easily the latest timestamp of each state by doing

```
SELECT id, name, MAX(timestamp) ts , state FROM states
GROUP BY id, name, state
ORDER BY ts
```

However, you could do what you want by dumping your table into a text file and do a simple script in which ever language you are confortable with, perl, ruby python etc. Even on a million row table that could be done quiet quickly

Comment: On a 4.3 billion row table that's going to take some time... and memory.

Comment: You only need to keep the last line on memory to detect consecutive duplicate. You can even use the `uniq` command to do it (see -f options). If its really billions of rows, I think 2 hours is a bit optmistic ;-)